# In javascript socket.emit is working but socket.on is not working

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io

I am working on a project, and here is the code

this is the code snippet

```js
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000'); // Connect to port 5000
    
        socket.on('new_image_content', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
            document.getElementById('imageContainer').appendChild(image);
        });
        
        function submitPrompt() {
            var prompt = document.getElementById('promptInput').value;
            socket.emit('prompt', { text: prompt });
        }
```

Here, the socket.on('new_image_content') is not working.

Here is the whole Source Code

Server.py

```py
import flask
import flask_socketio
import base64
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

# Configure the secret key
secret_key = "seckey"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = secret_key
socketio = flask_socketio.SocketIO(app)

# Wildcard cors enabled
socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

@socketio.on("connect")
def on_connect():
    print("Someone connected!")
    socketio.emit("connected", {"test": "Connected"})
    print("Sent connect message")

@socketio.on("disconnect")
def on_disconnect():
    print("Someone disconnected!")
    socketio.emit("disconnected", {"test": "Disconnected"})
    print("Sent disconnect message")

@socketio.on("prompt")
def on_message(data):
    print("Got message from client: " + str(data))

@socketio.on("new_image_content")
def on_new_image_content(data):
    print("Got new image content from client: " + str(data))
    print("..................................................................................")
   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

folder_watcher.py

```py
import os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import socketio
import base64

# Function to emit the content of new images in a folder
def emit_images_content(folder_path, sio):
    class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
        def on_created(self, event):
            if not event.is_directory:
                with open(event.src_path, 'rb') as file:
                    image_content = file.read()
                    # Encode the new image content as a base64 string
                    image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_content).decode('utf-8')

                print('New image created: ' + event.src_path)

                sio.emit('new_image_content', image_base64)

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), folder_path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio = socketio.Client()
    sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')

    # Replace 'your_folder_path' with the path of the folder you want to monitor for new images
    folder_path = 'images'  # Change this to your actual folder path
    emit_images_content(folder_path, sio)

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

client.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prompt Provider</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.1.3/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Prompt Provider</h1>
    <input id="promptInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter a prompt">
    <button onclick="submitPrompt()">Submit Prompt</button>

    <div id="imageContainer"></div> <!-- A container for images -->

    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000'); // Connect to port 5000
    
        socket.on('new_image_content', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
            document.getElementById('imageContainer').appendChild(image);
        });
        
        function submitPrompt() {
            var prompt = document.getElementById('promptInput').value;
            socket.emit('prompt', { text: prompt });
        }
    </script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some additional information to your question: 1) Are you getting an error on `new_image_content`?  2) What gets logged in the browser console by `console.log(data)`?  3) Is your Python server responding at port 5000 if you ping it?

Comment: In the console, there is nothing. But in the server where socket.on() it is working fine.